# bound picture to control in WPF without using converter

Tags: wpf, image, bind

i'm having a custom object with Picture as a string (file name only)
and i want to display.

the problem is that the image is stored in "images" directory of the project so the full path is now "images/{image name}"

how can i bind it correctly ?

i can do it easily with converter i guess, but is there any way to avoid it like:
`<Image Source="{Binding Path=FullPath+"/"+Picture}">` ?

Comment: You might be able to fool it with DataContext on the parent but I doubt the filename is treated like a Property of the directory.

Answer (score 1):

You could bind to an aggregated property in your ViewModel and then put whatever path you like into that. That way the ViewModel becomes the 'converter'.